# How to access a number of different objects from a dropdown menu?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to develop a web app which has a few separate pages and each page displays data from an array which holds a few different objects. What I am trying to do is display the data held in objects stored in separate arrays from a dropdown menu found on the home page.

```
const firstArray = [

   {
     name: "Item 1",
     info: "Info 1",
     img: "Img 1"
   },
   {
     name: "Item 2",
     info: "Info 2",
     img: "Img 2"
   },
   {
     name: "Item 3",
     info: "Info 3",
     img: "Img 3"
   },

]
```

There is a second and third array which follow the same model. The dropdown menu I am trying to tie this to is as follows:

```
 <ul>
     <h4>Creatures Anathema</h4>
      <li class="list-item first">Item 1</li>
      <li class="list-item first">Item 2</li>
      <li class="list-item first">Item 3</li>
      <li class="list-item second">Item 1</li>
      <li class="list-item second">Item 2</li>
      <li class="list-item second">Item 3</li>
      <li class="list-item third">Item 1</li>
      <li class="list-item third">Item 2</li>
      <li class="list-item third">Item 3</li>
 <!-- The class after "list-item" designates the array the item should be tied to, and the name of the item itself is an object property -->
 </ul>
```

So, for example, if you would click on

Item 3

with the class of second, that would display the information from the 3rd object held in the second Array. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the tour and read through the help center, in particular how to ask. Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. After doing more research and searching, post a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck, which can help you get better answers!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

You can achieve it with Javascript and some Regular expressions.

```
let listItems = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.list-item')); // array of .list-item

const classRegex = /first|second|third/gi; // to check the className
let data; // variable for storing data

listItems.map(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', ev => {
    let elem = ev.currentTarget;
    let arrayName = `${ elem.classList.value.match(classRegex)[0] }Array`; // get the class of clicked element

    // .find() finds the object which satisfies the given condition
    data = window[arrayName].find(obj => obj.name.toLowerCase() === elem.innerText.toLowerCase());
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

```js
const firstArray = [

   {
     name: "Item 1",
     info: "Info 1.1",
     img: "Img 1"
   },
   {
     name: "Item 2",
     info: "Info 1.2",
     img: "Img 2"
   },
   {
     name: "Item 3",
     info: "Info 1.3",
     img: "Img 3"
   },

];

const secondArray = [

   {
     name: "Item 1",
     info: "Info 2.1",
     img: "Img 1"
   },
   {
     name: "Item 2",
     info: "Info 2.2",
     img: "Img 2"
   },
   {
     name: "Item 3",
     info: "Info 2.3",
     img: "Img 3"
   },

];

const thirdArray = [

   {
     name: "Item 1",
     info: "Info 3.1",
     img: "Img 1"
   },
   {
     name: "Item 2",
     info: "Info 3.2",
     img: "Img 2"
   },
   {
     name: "Item 3",
     info: "Info 3.3",
     img: "Img 3"
   },

];

let listItems = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.list-item'));

const classRegex = /first|second|third/gi;
let data; // variable for storing data

listItems.map(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', ev => {
    let elem = ev.currentTarget;
    let arrayName = `${ elem.classList.value.match(classRegex)[0] }Array`;
    data = window[arrayName].find(obj => obj.name.toLowerCase() === elem.innerText.toLowerCase());
  
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

```html
<ul>
     <h4>Creatures Anathema</h4>
      <li class="list-item first">Item 1</li>
      <li class="list-item first">Item 2</li>
      <li class="list-item first">Item 3</li>
      <li class="list-item second">Item 1</li>
      <li class="list-item second">Item 2</li>
      <li class="list-item second">Item 3</li>
      <li class="list-item third">Item 1</li>
      <li class="list-item third">Item 2</li>
      <li class="list-item third">Item 3</li>
 <!-- The class after "list-item" designates the array the item should be tied to, and the name of the item itself is an object property -->
 </ul>
```